# Post checkbox value in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to post checkbox value and store it,but my post value is shown as on.

**View**

```
<label for="name">Programme Applied for:</label><br>
<br>
<input name="program" type="checkbox">Six Months Computerized Accounting Diploma<br>
<input name="program" type="checkbox">Six Months Computerized Accounting Diploma<br>
<input name="program" type="checkbox">Two Months Diploma in taxation (Direct)<br>
<input name="program" type="checkbox">Three Months Diploma in taxation (Direct & Indirect)<br>
<input name="program" type="checkbox">One Year Diploma in Accounting Finance Taxation <br>
<input name="program" type="checkbox">Banking and Payroll
<br><br>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('program'); ?></div>
```

**Controller**

```
$data=array('prg_applied' => $this->input->post('program'));
$insert = $this->firstmodel->insert_record($data);
```

Comment: you have have value field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have value field, if you dont have value field then it will show "on" for checked boxes

```
 <input name="program" type="checkbox" value='Three Months Diploma in taxation (Direct & Indirect)'>Three Months Diploma in taxation (Direct & Indirect)<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want [radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radio) rather than checkbox. Then you can have multiple selectable inputs of the same `name` and different `value`, where the selected box will provide value in the HTTP request.

You also use `<label>` wrong. It is supposed to be for individual inputs:

```
<label><input name="program">Six Months Computerized…</label><br>
```

Or:

```
<input name="program" id="x"> <label for="x">Six Months Computerized…</label><br>
```